# Segregating Springboot app for DEV and PROD Environment for the email app

Tags: spring-boot, email, environment-variables

My springboot App is working fine in DEV environment, and now i would like to segregate DEV and PROD environments in order for it to pickup respective code.

I did go through few of the tutorials got some lead to it but was not able to come conclusion on how to separate out PROD section.

This app basically sends an email to gmail on form submission from angular app. This is what i have done till now on the springboot app in order to segregate it.

I have created `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` from the actual `application.properties` file and added two separate gmail accounts one for DEV and one for PROD. And added the Profiles to POM.xml

Any help on how to create a PROD environment from the existing code will be very helpful. I am quite new to springboot and how to go about doing profiling for different environments.

application.properties file (actual file) is :

```
server.port=8084

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=test1@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

New application-dev.properties file

```
server.port=8084
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=test1@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true

spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@
```

New application-prod.properties file

```
server.port=8085
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=test2@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

POM.xml file

```
<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <properties>
    <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
  </properties>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
  </activation>
</profile>
<profile>
  <id>prod</id>
  <properties>
    <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Main EmailClientHmwApplication.java file  is as below:

```
package com.sami.EmailClientHMW;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EmailClientHmwApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailClientHmwApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My MailController file which is working with DEV  is as :

```
package com.sami.EmailClientHMW.controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@RestController
public class MailController {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @GetMapping("/testsite")
    public String Testing()
    {
        return "Welcome to HMW Email Client Version..New!!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/mail")
    @CrossOrigin
    public String sendmail(@RequestBody MailRequest request) {
        sendSimpleEmail(request.getFrom(), request.getBody(), request.getSubject());
        return "email sent successfully";
    }

    private void sendSimpleEmail(
            String fromEmail,
            String body,
            String subject)
    {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setFrom("test1@gmail.com");
        message.setTo("test1@gmail.com");
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
            mailSender.send(message);
        System.out.println("From DEV Mail Sent Successfully..hmw!!");
    }
}
```

MailRequest file:

```
package com.sami.EmailClientHMW.controller;

public class MailRequest {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String body;

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also trying the build the project using the command  clean install -Pprod so that profile prod gets activated however it keeps hitting 8084 port of application-dev.properties or application.properties(not sure which of these two) instead 8085 of application-prod.properties.  Not sure what wrong i am doing here, i would like to build with prod profile so it runs on port 8085.

Comment: please (always) remember: maven is for "build", spring is for "runtime".. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explaination, so i go with this approach of spring.profiles.active=@activatedProperties@, i should add this to all my application.properties file(dev n prod)? And how exactly should i run maven build for prod? Kindly excuse me for my slow n low understanding on how springboot works.

Comment: this is "mixing maven with spring profiles", which i *dont recommend*, but yes.. one file should be sufficient, but also consider: there can/could be higher precedence settings! (e.g. command line/System/env  will override application.properties..)

Comment: and the `@...@` is replaced by maven, when we build.... but do we want to build for prod something different than for dev!?? I (and more clever people) say: No! (ideally same jar/war, with *identical bytes*)

Comment: Thanks, i think i am getting the point you are telling. So basically post maven build of the jar file, its the way you run it,  If i use "java -jar target/myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod", this will take all properties of application-prod.properties..correct.? Kindly excuse if my understanding is still wrong.

Comment: No need to excuse! :-) You get it right! (i hope/it sounds like!). And with my "General Tip#2", you can also skip that in one (of the two, later maybe more...?) environments. since it would be the "default environment". (Not to confuse with "default" profile in spring, which we can also mis-/use)

Comment: @xerx593 Thanks alot, your suggestion worked for me as i expected. :)

Comment: One other quick doubt is how do i call the variable from application properties 
adding following variable:
env=DEV -- in application-dev.properties

in the controller file i have added the following:


    @Autowired
    @Value("${env}")
    private static String env1;

 System.out.println(env1);
        System.out.println("From" + env1 + " Mail Sent Successfully..hmw!!");

but when i run the app, i get the null value for env1

kindly help here too pls.

Comment: `static` (!) sneaky , but wrong! :-)

Comment: Perfect :), removed static and got the value. Thanks once again. Highly Appreciate your support.

Comment: Cewl! 8-) Very welcome! ;) (please consider to "accept";)

Comment: @xerx593 Welcome :), if you can help with the another question i had posted last week that would be also very helpful to complete my website. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635712/my-email-form-submit-condition-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have created `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties` from the actual `application.properties`

This is already *very good* (except the exposing secrets in git part...), and you are in fact done!

To activate/override them, you just need to set `spring.profiles.active` on the according environment.

This can be done trough one of the 14(!) [spring-boot](/questions/tagged/spring-boot) defined property sources in [Chapter 2, Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config), e.g.:

- (`java.lang.`)System property (6.):

  ```bash
  java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod target/myApp.jar
  ```
- also convenient: (5.) Env variables (we have to apply ["relaxed rules"..](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding)):

  ```bash
  # in windows: SET SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
  export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
  java -jar target/myApp.jar
  ```
- or 11. (different, and more prioritized than 6.):

  ```bash
  java -jar target/myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod
  ```
- ... (I recommend something "below 5.", though it is ) also possible in `application.properties` (3.)

---

#### General Tipps:

- Don't "double maintain" common properties like:

  ```properties
  spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
  spring.mail.port=587
  # ...
  spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
  # ...
  ```

  for these single location (`application.properties`) is ok!
- Use or `dev` or `prod` (recommended) properties in `application.properties`, which adds you "default behavior" (with its benefits (less to care about/maintain) & trade-offs (more to forget/hidden))

##### How to achieve profile activation on PROD

- Or use `prod` properties as `application.properties` (recommended, "opt-in" DEV+other environments)
- Or activate it in one of the ways proposed above.

##### How to achieve profile activation on DEV (*with IDE*)

If we chose DEV as `application.properties`, then this is also accomplished (and maybe even to prefer for very "dev driven"/prototype environments).

If we chose PROD as `application.properties`, then we need to do basically the same for DEV -  set `spring.profiles.active`:

- add `spring.profiles.active=dev` *property* to our maven/gradle build (configuration, in IDE)
- or add `--spring.profiles.active=dev` *parameter* on our spring-boot:run (configuration, in IDE)
- I would not mix maven profiles with spring profiles, if you don't really have good reason for, but if...
- On the spring-boot-maven(/gradle)-plugin, you can set it like:

  > ```xml
  > <project>
  >    <properties>
  >        <app.profiles>local,dev</app.profiles>
  >    </properties>
  >    <build>
  >        <plugins>
  >            <plugin>
  >                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  >                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  >                <configuration>
  >                    <profiles>${app.profiles}</profiles>
  >                </configuration>
  >            </plugin>
  >        </plugins>
  >    </build>
  > </project>
  > ```

  [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.overriding-command-line)

#### In Tests

It depends:

- in which (of all) environment(s) will it run?
- what profile should it use?

We have the very handy [spring-test](/questions/tagged/spring-test) annotation [`@ActiveProfiles`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html), but its value should be quite "fixed" (for all environments, where tests are run).

When this is not sufficient, consider to introduce an extra profile(group)/setting for tests.

But we can also pass the `spring.profiles.active` property to (e.g) `maven-surefire/failesafe-plugin`, like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=${some.maven.property}</argLine>
</configuration>
```

#### For Secrets

[Spring Boot (admits&) recommends](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.encrypting):

> Spring Boot does not provide any built in support for encrypting property values, however, it does provide the hook points necessary to modify values contained in the Spring Environment. The `EnvironmentPostProcessor` interface allows you to manipulate the Environment before the application starts. See [howto.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.application.customize-the-environment-or-application-context) for details.

> If you need a secure way to store credentials and passwords, the [Spring Cloud Vault](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/) project provides support for storing externalized configuration in [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/).

Though container/cloud-driven, spring-boot has no real support for:

##### Docker Secrets

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

...but there are [several articles/so-questions/github-respositories around](https://www.google.com/search?q=docker%20secrets%20spring%20boot), targeting that use case.

---

More Links:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-definition-profiles
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-property-source-abstraction (ff)